# Add class to link slug based off array of slugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am creating a recipe tool that takes a user's input via selected checkboxes. See here: [zelda.wptoolkit.us](http://zelda.wptoolkit.us)

Part One:
I have a script that will create an array of slugs based off of the selected input values. When a user clicks a checkbox, the associated slug is added to an array called checkedAttr.

```
<script>
var checkedAttr = [];

$('#wp-advanced-search :checkbox').change(function() 
{
checkedAttr = [];
$('#wp-advanced-search :checkbox').each(function(i, item){
    if($(item).is(':checked'))
    {
        checkedAttr.push($(item).val()); 
    }
});
console.log("checkedAttr:", checkedAttr);
});
</script>
```

Part Two:
I am trying to use the code below to `.addClass` to any links that contain a slug found in the array from part one.

The link structure: `http://zelda.wptoolkit.us/tag/any-crab/`

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#wpas-results-inner > div > div > p > a[href^="/tag/' + 
location.pathname.split("/") this.checkedAttr[0] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

What I am aiming to do is target the links in each card, then add a class to the links whose slug is found in my array. The end goal is to highlight checked 'ingredients' and fade out ingredients that haven't been checked.

I am not exactly sure how to make this function check my array for each slug, I would love to learn what steps are needed to accomplish this!

I am also not certain if my jQuery CSS path is correctly targeting the links

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I would certainly remove the array instantiation within the `change` function `checkedAttr = [];` and just keep the declaration outside the `change` function. Also `this.checkedAttr[0]` will add the same path to everything.

Comment: Please show relevant html structure as per [mcve]

Comment: what you want if we click on check box and if its check and apply the class `active` on your relative card block? and if its un-check and remove the class `active`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like when select particular checkbox, all the card related to that checkbox should be enabled(lets say apply any class `active`) and once you dis-select the checkbox, we need to remove that particular class from all related checkbox??

you can check the given fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/x1L95dw3/1/

```
var checkedAttr = [];

$('#checkBoxForCategory :checkbox').change(function() 
{
        var cardCategory = $(this).val();    
    var allCards = $('.myCard[card-category=' + cardCategory + ']');

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
            //add the selected category to array
        checkedAttr.push(cardCategory); 

        //add the `active` class for all the card belongs to selected category
        $(allCards).each(function()
        {
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //remove from array
      var index = checkedAttr.indexOf(cardCategory);
      checkedAttr.splice(index, 1);

      //remove the class for all the card belongs to selected category
        $(allCards).each(function()
      {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
    }    

    console.log("checkedAttr:", checkedAttr);
});
```

Comment: Hey! This looks great! But perhaps I need to clarify my question. My goal is to have the ingredients in the card change color when their corresponding option in the form is selected. I.e. the ingredients would default to a gray color, and then become highlighted as they are selected in the form.

Comment: yes that we have done in example.. initial background is `white` and test color is `blue`, once you select it, it will revert the color. background `blue` and text color `white`, you can use your own color

Comment: Understood, but I am aiming to change the individual ingredient link's class so the links change color, not the card background. Perhaps I am not making myself clear enough, sorry!

Comment: aaahh so you mean under the card you have one link and you want to change the color of that link, not the complete card right??